# How can I remove an entire entry from a JSON file based on a match for the value of a key in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file output by a bit of software, and I'm looking to separate the entries in the JSON file based on the `type` of a given entry. The structure of the JSON file is like so:

```
{
  "Overall": [
    {
      "coeffs": [
        0.5,
        1.0
      ],
      "name": "LinearFit"
    }
  ],
  "Points": [
    {
      "coeffs": [
        -0.78,
        0.02
      ],
      "xvalue": "1995",
      "type": "DataPoint"
    },
    {
      "coeffs": [
        -0.54,
        0.00
      ],
      "xvalue": "1997",
      "type": "DataPoint"
    },
    {
      "coeffs": [
        -0.77,
        0.02
      ],
      "xvalue": "1998",
      "type": "InterpolatedData"
    },
    {
      "coeffs": [
        -0.66,
        0.23
      ],
      "xvalue": "1999",
      "type": "InterpolatedData"
    },
    {
      "coeffs": [
        -0.51,
        0.01
      ],
      "xvalue": "2000",
      "type": "DataPoint"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the Python script below which I have been using to remove all entries in `Points` with `type == InterpolatedData`, but when running this, not all cases are removed. To be clear, the output I'm trying to write should be

```
{
  "Overall": [
    {
      "coeffs": [
        0.5,
        1.0
      ],
      "name": "LinearFit"
    }
  ],
  "Points": [
    {
      "coeffs": [
        -0.78,
        0.02
      ],
      "xvalue": "1995",
      "type": "DataPoint"
    },
    {
      "coeffs": [
        -0.54,
        0.00
      ],
      "xvalue": "1997",
      "type": "DataPoint"
    },
    {
      "coeffs": [
        -0.51,
        0.01
      ],
      "xvalue": "2000",
      "type": "DataPoint"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the code I'm using (I use ArgumentParser in terminal, I thought I'd mention this in the question in case this was possibly the cause of the issue):

```
import json
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter

def main(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for entry in data['Points']:
        if entry['type']=='InterpolatedData':
            data['Points'].remove(entry)
    with open('./LinearFitUsingDataOnly.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data,f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("json", type=str, help="JSON file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.json)
```

so I'd run this in terminal with the command

```
$ python myPythonScript.py LinearFitAllPoints.json
```

My output doesn't remove all instances of entries of type `InterpolatedData`, only the `"xvalue": "1998"` entry (i.e. the first one it comes across). Any help would be appreciated, as I can't get my head around why the code above doesn't remove all cases (I've also tried delete, giving me the same result).

Comment: "I've also tried delete": what does this mean?

Comment: Should have said `del`, as in I tried `del entry` but with no luck (in place of the `data['Points'].remove(entry)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing

```
for entry in data['Points']:
```

by

```
for entry in list(data['Points']):
```

you create a copy of your entries instead of iterating over them while deleting, which, in general, is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you - that's worked perfectly! Didn't properly consider how I was handling the file, yeah that was bad coding practice!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```
input = <Your Dict>

point = input['Points']

for line in point:
  if isinstance(line, dict):
    value = line['type']
    if value is 'InterpolatedData':
      del line['type']

print(input)
```

> {'Overall': [{'coeffs': [0.5, 1.0], 'name': 'LinearFit'}], 'Points': [{'coeffs': [-0.78, 0.02], 'xvalue': '1995', 'type': 'DataPoint'}, {'coeffs': [-0.54, 0.0], 'xvalue': '1997', 'type': 'DataPoint'}, {'coeffs': [-0.77, 0.02], 'xvalue': '1998'}, {'coeffs': [-0.66, 0.23], 'xvalue': '1999'}, {'coeffs': [-0.51, 0.01], 'xvalue': '2000', 'type': 'DataPoint'}]}

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get this to work off-the-bat: so I'd need to convert my read-in JSON file to a dict or tuple? I get an error `TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types`

Comment: Isinstance is for fail safe. And no need to convert it to any dict or tuple as json is already dict in python